# C++ std::set upper_bound iterator behaviour

Tags: c++11, stl, iterator, set

I had a lookup problem to code and was unsure about correct interpretation of iterator testing.  The problem is this:  I have a set and do a lookup using upper_bound, then want to find the next lowest element.  Like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <algorithm>

void exploreSet(std::set<int> &int_set, int key);

int main()
{
    std::set<int> int_set { 5, 10, 12, 17, 19 };
    exploreSet(int_set, 15);
    exploreSet(int_set, 4);
    return 0;
}


void exploreSet(std::set<int> &int_set, int key)
{
    auto it = int_set.upper_bound(key);
    if ( it==int_set.end() )
    {
        std::cout << "Nothing found.\n";
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Found " << *it << ".\n";
        // Now find the next lowest value -- how?
        auto it_back = it;
        --it_back;
        if ( it_back==int_set.end() )
        {
            std::cout << "Nothing prior.\n";
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Prior value:  " << *it_back << ".\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Resulting output of running this on gcc 4.9.2 with std=c++14:

```
Found 17.
Prior value:  12.
Found 5.
Nothing prior.
```

This works.  But why?

Is it correct to compare against std::set::end() when going backwards on an iterator obtained through upper_bound?  Why or why not?

Comment: Why are you not simply using `lower_bound`?  On a `set` it goes straight to what you want.

Comment: @MooingDuck only if you use `std::greater` as comparator for the set

Comment: @AntonSavin: I'm super confused by your comment.  His algorithm seems to be displaying the largest value less than or equal to the given key in a container ordered by `std::less`, which is exactly what `lower_bound` does by default.  Did I misunderstand something?

Comment: @MooingDuck `lower_bound` finds the smallest value greater or equal to the given key.

Comment: Maybe lower_bound does the job, but I couldn't tell based on the documentation on cppreference.com:  According to http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set, lower_bound "returns an iterator to the first element not less than the given key", whereas upper_bound "returns an iterator to the first element greater than the given key".  The meaning of "first element" in that description throws me.

Comment: If the key is not in the set, `lower_bound(key)` is the same as `upper_bound(key)`.

Comment: @AntonSavin: Oh geez, right.  I had `lower_bound` wrong in my head.  It's not helpful here.  Nevermind me.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's incorrect. Decrementing iterator equal to `begin()` is undefined behavior. See [bidirectional.iterators]/1, Table 110:

> **Expression**
>      `--r`
>   **Assertion/note pre-/post-condition**
>      pre: there exists `s` such that `r == ++s`.
>      post: `r` is dereferenceable.

So the correct way is to compare `it` with `int_set.begin()`:

```
// Now find the next lowest value -- how?
if ( it == int_set.begin() )
{
    std::cout << "Nothing prior.\n";
}
else
{
    auto it_back = it;
    --it_back;
    std::cout << "Prior value:  " << *it_back << ".\n";
}
```

That said, I would instead advise using `std::set<int, std::greater<int>>` together with `lower_bound`:

```
template <typename Set>
void exploreSet(const Set& int_set, int key) {
    auto it = int_set.lower_bound(key);
    if (it == int_set.end())
        std::cout << "Nothing found.\n";
    else
        std::cout << "Found " << *it << ".\n";
}

int main() {
    std::set<int, std::greater<int>> int_set { 5, 10, 12, 17, 19 };
    exploreSet(int_set, 15);
    exploreSet(int_set, 4);
}
```